# php send variables to another file without form

Tags: php, variables, send

I've looked at so many stack overflow questions to find my solution, but none of the questions I try are what I am looking for (so if you know of one that fits my question, please tell me). What I have is a php page that processes a form. It looks like this:

```
<?php
$var1 = htmlentities($_POST['var1']);
$var2 = htmlentities($_POST['var2']);

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
$query = "INSERT INTO table (var1,var2) VALUES ('$var2','$var2)";
$doQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if($doQuery) {
    // this is where script should go (i think) to send the variables to the email page
header("Location: /path/to/next/page"); // this just sends the user to the next page. NOT PART OF EMAIL PAGE
}

else {
header("Location: /path/to/back/page");
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

so its a basic form handler that sends you to the next page if all goes well.

I have another page that is sends an email notification to someone when they successfully go through the first page. It also processes all of the other email notification worthy forms as well. that's the reason I can't just take the script and put it into the top page.

So, what I am trying to do is figure out a way to send the `$var1` and `$var2` to the email file without completely redirecting the user. I don't need a response back from the email file.

I hope that made sense.

thanks in advance

Comment: You just want to include the file where its needed http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: you have a syntax error - `echo 'error';` doesn't help you, if that's your actual code.

Comment: its not. thanks though @Fred-ii-

Comment: it (still) is for future readers ;-) please edit respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple, really:

```
// your code above
require 'send-email.php';
```

And your `send-email.php` would reference `$var1` and `$var2`.

Comment: so I wouldn't need to `$_GET` or `$_POST` the variables?

Comment: @phprunner No - try it and you'll see.